# How is Coq pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

The Coq proof assistant does not seem to specify a pronunciation on its [website](https://coq.inria.fr/about-coq), nor does the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq) page list a pronunciation. How should its name be pronounced?

Comment: However you wish.

Comment: Whichever way is most natural for you.

Comment: The obvious way until someone “corrects” you. Then switch to “coke” ;o)

Comment: The French Coq is the  nickname for "calcule de construction", which is calculus of construction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Judging from the comments in this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/6ocu5s/how_does_one_properly_pronounce_coq/), the pronunciation is /kɑk/ ([source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cock#Pronunciation)).

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Mebbe Reddit is like the anti-StackExchange. Shame that the only answer to a pronunciation question that uses IPA is downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

The word *coq*, which is the French word for "cock", meaning male chicken or rooster, in English sees almost exclusive use in the name of the French dish [coq au vin](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coq%20au%20vin), and is pronounced either like "coke" or like "cock".

Comment: When I see it I think of the "food supplement" CoQ10, which is fairly universally pronounced "co que ten".

Comment: I think it’s more like “cuck” than either coke or cock.

Comment: To elaborate on the Coq proof assistant software mentioned in the question (which I work with): in my experience, most anglophones working with Coq either pronounce it as they would pronounce *cock*, or else aim to replicate the standard French pronunciation, which doesn’t quite correspond to any English vowel.  I’ve never heard anyone go for a fully English *coke* vowel when speaking of the proof assistant.